# Lypanunov equation: check if a given $\Sigma$ is a solution to a Lyapunov equation? What happens for p.s.d. matrizes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory, positive-definite, lyapunov-functions

I was recently made aware in another post of the Lyapunov equation, so now I am trying to understand it a bit better and therefore have two questions.

In the following, we assume that $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that all eigenvalues of $M$ have real parts and $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ will always be symmetric matrizes.

Now, the Lypanuov equation in this situation reads
$$ M\Sigma + \Sigma M^T = P,$$
and the associated theory assures that for $P$ positive definite, there is always a $\Sigma$ positive definite such that the above equation is fullfilled.

---

Now, my first question would be, given fixed $M$ and $\Sigma$ positive definite, can we somehow find a simple criterion whether the result is positive definite? That is, can we easily read out whether a $\Sigma$ solves a Lyapunov equation for some $P$?

---

My second question would now be, what happens if we have that $\Sigma$ is only positive semi definite?

It seems like in this situation, one can still tweak around to get a positive semi-definite $P$: Assume we know the Kernel $K$ of $\Sigma$, and define an operator $U$ that is $\mu \ Id$ on $K$ for $\mu>=0$ and $0$ else (this should be possible to be taken symmetric by taking using the decomposition $\Sigma = ODO^T$ and replacing the diagonals of $D$ appropiately). Then $$ \Sigma + U$$ is a positive definite matrix.

Thus, if we could show that $\Sigma + U$ solves a Lyapunov equation for $P$ then $\Sigma$ would also solve a Lyapunov equation for the positive semidefinite matrix $P- (MU + UM^T)$, where we have to impose some conditions on $\mu$. (If I am not mistaken, $\mu< \frac{p_{\min}}{2|m_{max}|}$ should be enough, where $p_{\min}$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $P$ and $m_{\max}$ the largest one of $M$).
Does this construction work indeed or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I assume you meant that $P$ is negative definite (at least that is usually used in the context of control, with $M$ having only eigenvalues whose real part is negative)? And for your first question one can always just calculate the resulting $P$ given the matrices $M$ and $\Sigma$.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen yes I have seen that most sources use negative definite by now, but I mean this should not really matter as one could use $-M$ and $-P$ instead. And yeah, my first question was maybe phrased a bit losely, I mean of course if there is some criterion on $M$, given $\Sigma$ or on $\Sigma$, given $M$, i.e. can we exploit some of the facts we know about these matrizes